# Solving nonlinear integral equation

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, closed-form

Are there some known techniques for solving $h(x)=f(x)\int_0^xf(t)dt$ for $f(x)$? Are there closed form solutions?

Comment: I was surprised there was no "integral equations" tag!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$. Then $F'=f$, so that the integral equation transforms into the differential equation
$$
F'F=h,\quad F(0)=0.
$$
Integrating we get
$$
\frac12 F^2=\int_0^xh(t)\,dt\implies F(x)=\sqrt{2\int_0^xh(t)\,dt}
$$
and
$$
f(x)=F'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{h(x)}{\sqrt{\int_0^xh(t)\,dt}}.
$$